# Synonym for "Register activities"

Tags: synonyms

I'm currently in the process of designing an app for the smartphone, but I'm running into a linguistic issue. In the app you're supposed to be able to keep track of what you did on a day, and see how much energy that costs you. I've got the following three screens:

- Register activities
- Total
- Today

The screen "Register activities" allows you to log what activities you did that day. "Total" will show how much energy you used up, and "Today" shows the activities you registered that day.

My problem is that, though "Total" and "Today" are simple and straight-forward words, "Register activities" is far from. Therefore I'm looking for a single word that bears the same meaning. Ideally this word would also be easily translatable, though that's not a requirement.

Comment: How about:  Record

Comment: @Val with record I'd think of "turn it on, do some activities, hit save, done". I guess I'm looking for something more active (if it exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you gave the answer yourself: "log".

You could call it "Log", or "Activity Log".  People would get it.

Just as an aside, if Total is really about energy, I'd call it "Energy".  It's much more fun sounding.  ;-)